# Path-Based Vulnerability on security report on images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are running Qualys security tests on our angular webapp, and we are getting one issue. Whatever images we are loading in the screens, we are getting "Path-Based Vulnerability" issue for those image links...

We are adding images like: `<img  src="assets/icons/img1.svg"/>`

If I access this URL: `example.com/xyz/assets/icons`, I get 403 Forbidden.

But with `example.com/xyz/assets/icons/img1.svg`  I can access the image publicly.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: What further info does Qualys give about the vulnerability? It should give a reason why it thinks there is a problem.

Comment: Being able to view image files that are referenced from HTML (and not to view directory contents) is entirely normal and in no way a vulnerability. Is your scanner (or its documentation) saying anything about else about the vulnerability, such as what the exploit scenario is or what you're supposed to do to mitigate it? Are you sure the paths in the report are the same as in your HTML?